# App is scrolling to the top when hooks are updated

Tags: reactjs

My app is using function components with hooks, any time a hook is updated the page is scrolled to the top.

How do you use hooks without it doing this?

```
export default function UserProduct(props) {
    // Setup variables and react hooks
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    
    async function ExpandProduct(event) {
        var call = await ProductsTransactionsAPI(props.product.pk, props.product.type);
        if (call.Success) {
            setTransactions(call.Data.Transactions);
        }
        setExpanded(true);
    }

    return (
            <div style={{borderBottom: '1px solid #e0e0e0'}}>
                <div className="user-product" style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                    <div className="user-product-title">
                        <img src={image} height='75px'/>
                        {props.product.name}
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" onClick={() => ExpandProduct()}><ExpandMoreIcon/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: It's because the web browser treats it as a hyperlink... how do I prevent the "a" html tag from scrolling to top when clicked. If I change "a" to "span" and leave the onClick, the function executes properly and the page does not scroll to top - but when my mouse is over the button there is no clickable hand symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this has to do with the HTML a tag... it is treating this as a link when I really just want it to run a javascript function.

So we change this line:

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => ExpandProduct()}><ExpandMoreIcon/></a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick={() => ExpandProduct()}><ExpandMoreIcon/></a>
```